# How to fill boxes in geom_point legend with color of points, not just increasing their size?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having a similar problem as described in [here under "2- After having the two legends..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27037611/), but instead of increasing the point size (which eventually also enlarges the legend itself), I would like fill each box in the legend with the corresponding color. Like in a bar plot's legend. [Data & code examples here](https://github.com/KonScience/Summarize-Flattr-Reports/commit/9e64219e347fc6233fcd1991bf3e5f9e88ef702f).

Looking through several other questions here, the ggplot docu, etc., I tried variations of code-snippets I found, but couldn't figure out a solution. The legend always retained the point symbols.

Therefore: If possible, how to tweak or replace the legend of a point/scatter/bubble plot so that it looks like the legend of a bar plot? Or, more generally, how to replace the legend of a given geom in ggplot2 with that of a different one? Thank you for any hints!

**Edit: Example with mtcars data**

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point(aes(colour = factor(cyl), size = qsec))
p
```

Adding what I gathered from other SO-answers...

```
p <- p + guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = unique(mtcars$cyl))))
p
```

...keeps the points, instead of expanding the color to fill the legend box, no matter arguments and datasources I try for guides() and list().

On the other hand:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = factor(cyl)), stat="identity")
```

...draws nicely color-filled boxes to the legend. That's what I'm trying to do for a bubble plot.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please try to narrow down the code? Adding images will also be helpful.

Comment: Oh, I assumed code on GitHub with example csv. would be sufficient, sorry. Added minimal code above. I can't post pictures yet, but I hope the description in combination with the standard example data is clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ggplot2 custom legend shapes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456765/ggplot2-custom-legend-shapes)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12751159/ggplot2-making-changes-to-symbols-in-the-legend/12751397#12751397

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You won't be able to get a `fill`-type legend per se, but you can easily emulate it:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = factor(cyl), size = qsec)) + 
  guides(col = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 15, size = 10)))
```

[image]